# Lua - Writing a multidimensional array to file issue

Tags: arrays, lua, io

so I set up a multidimensional array on construction. The array is my attempt at an occupancy grid and if I index the array by literals it's completely fine. However, during the main loop, I work out where the player in terms of the array and then loop a certain square radius around that element in the grid and print that portion to file. It works until the player moves from the original grid location I worked out, its very weird and I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Constructor:

```
occupancyGrid = {}
gridSize = 500 -- Each element in the grid is equivalent to 0.1 units of the environment space
gridElementSize = 0.1 -- The number of units in the evironment 1 element consists of
sensorRange = 5
for i=1,gridSize,1 do
    occupancyGrid[i] = {}
    for j=1,gridSize,1 do
        occupancyGrid[i][j] = 1
    end
end
```

Main Loop:

```
    print("[" .. simTime .. "] Saving partial map to file.")
    file = io.open(folderPath.."robotSurroundings.txt", "w+")
    io.output(file)
    
    local robotPosInGrid = getGridIndex({ robotPosition[1], robotPosition[2] })
    x=robotPosInGrid[1]
    y=robotPosInGrid[2]
    print(x .. ", " .. y)
        
    for i=y,y+10,1 do
        for j=x,x+10,1 do
            if(occupancyGrid[j][i] ~= nil) then
                io.write(occupancyGrid[i][j])
            end
        end
        io.write('\n')
    end
    io.close(file)
```

I apologise there is still a lot of testing code in there but the code still is pretty clear. But I work out where the robot is in terms of the grid and I write the next ten elements in both directions. The robot starts at a grid space of [250][250] but as soon as it moves to [249][250] it crashes and gives me the

```
 221: attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)
```

on the io.write line. I can't for the life of me figure out why because the logic seems correct here and if I index the grid with number literals its fine even if I write an if statement as such

```
if(occupancyGrid[j][i] == 0) then ...
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Console Photo

[image: 1]

Entire code function

```
function saveGrid(wholeGrid)
if(wholeGrid) then
    print("[" .. simTime .. "] Saving whole map to file.")
    file = io.open(folderPath.."wholeMap.txt", "w+")
    io.output(file)
        
    -- Write the entire grid to file
    for i=1,gridSize,1 do
        for j=1,gridSize,1 do
            io.write(occupancyGrid[j][i])
        end
        io.write('\n')
    end
else
    print("[" .. simTime .. "] Saving partial map to file.")
    file = io.open(folderPath.."robotSurroundings.txt", "w+")
    io.output(file)
    
    local robotPosInGrid = getGridIndex({ robotPosition[1], robotPosition[2] })
    x=robotPosInGrid[2]
    y=robotPosInGrid[1]
    print(x .. ", " .. y)
        
    for i=y,y+10,1 do
        for j=x,x+10,1 do
            if(occupancyGrid[j][i] ~= nil) then
                io.write(occupancyGrid[j][i])
            end
        end
        io.write('\n')
    end
end
io.close(file)
```

end

Comment: what does `print(x .. ", " .. y)`   print? your code works with x=249, y = 250 using the 500x500 grid

Comment: It prints 249,250 before the crash

Comment: did you modify the grid between both snippets? Lua values don't disappear by themselves.

Comment: No, the only function other than the constructor where the grid is touched is the save grid function which does have two parts, one where the entire grid is saved, the other only partial. The entire grid save is the same code but iterates over the entire grid and that doesn't have any issues

Comment: I've edited my main post, it now contains all the code that reference the grid.

Comment: Add a print to the loop to find out which index is failing. the only way to get this error is that a table in your table is missing. It ran just fine with the grid from your constructor

Comment: It might happen that `249` is not integer number.  Insert `assert(x==math.floor(x) and y==math.floor(y))` after `print(x .. ", " .. y)`

Answer (score 0):

Running the following code

```
occupancyGrid = {}
gridSize = 500 -- Each element in the grid is equivalent to 0.1 units of the environment space
for i=1,gridSize,1 do
    occupancyGrid[i] = {}
    for j=1,gridSize,1 do
        occupancyGrid[i][j] = 1
    end
end

local robotPosInGrid = {249, 250}
x=robotPosInGrid[1]
y=robotPosInGrid[2]
print(x .. ", " .. y)
       
for i=y,y+10,1 do
  for j=x,x+10,1 do
    if(occupancyGrid[j][i] ~= nil) then
      io.write(occupancyGrid[j][i])
    end
  end
  io.write('\n')
end
```

prints

```
249, 250
11111111111
11111111111
11111111111
11111111111
11111111111
11111111111
11111111111
11111111111
11111111111
11111111111
11111111111
```

to the console (or your default outputfile)

So I assume that you have removed a table from `occupancyGrid` as this is the only way to get that error message in this code.

Comment: Yeah, that code works if I manually provide the values, I have no problems accessing the elements through if statements, printing commands, etc but as soon I as write the element to file when providing the player's position as the base value for my offsets (whose value is completely valid), it becomes unhappy. All the code that references the grid is seen in the main post, its a single file and I havent missed anything off, so im at huge loss here

Comment: as I said, the only way to get this error is by indexing a non-existent field in your table. in your case that means `occupancyGrid[j]` is `nil` for at least one value of `j` in that loop.

Comment: I completely agree with what you're saying but I've print all elements from [240][240] - [260][260] and they print a value of 1 to console. It can access any element fine in the context of if statements, prints but when it comes to writing, blurgh. I might have to find an alternate approach.

Comment: If you are sure that row exists, make sure you're using the right index as in j being an integer

Comment: Does Lua have issues with iterating over arrays in the inner loop when using variables as indexes

Comment: no Lua has no issue with variables. but if your getGrindIndex functioin does not return integers but floats you will run into a problem als [0.00000001] is not [0]

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening because your j variable got out of bounds (bigger than the size of occupancyGrid).

As a result, `occupancyGrid[j]` returns nil and `occupancyGrid[j][i]` then equals to `(nil)[i]` which throws an error because nil cannot be indexed.